# VirtualWebAppLoader works fine. But same set of jars doesnt work when included in tomcat/lib/

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am new to Tomcat and has been working with virtualWebAppLoader in Tomcat7. It works fine. But, when i include the same set of third party jar files in either tomcat/lib and use common loader or put them in shared/lib and use shared loader the services does not return any data. Set of jar files remain the same in every loader but they work only with virtualWebAppLoader . Deployment logs are identical in all the deployments in catalina.out. But when i hit a service using XHR , i get the following logs which are identical to deployment logs:

```
Sep 11, 2017 10:41:57 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.16 11/28/2012 02:09 PM'
Sep 11, 2017 10:42:07 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
  /WEB-INF/lib
  /WEB-INF/classes
Sep 11, 2017 10:42:07 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.abc.Class1
  class com.abc.Class2
Sep 11, 2017 10:42:07 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Sep 11, 2017 10:42:07 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.16 11/28/2012 02:09 PM
```

On every hit through XHR i get the above logs. I dont know if it is due to a missing jar or clashing jars. But the set of jars are same in all the loaders and it works well in VirtualWebAppLoader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause. I had a common dependency of a project jar in multiple projects and looks like it is getting loaded twice with different class loaders. But I am still not able to figure out why it does not happen with VirtualWebAppLoader.